# Как открыть webview поверх всего приложения?

Tags: android

При переходе с первой activity на вторую нужно, чтобы webview открывалось поверх всего приложения, а не в новой activity.

Comment: А почему вы считаете что новая активити не поверх всего приложения? Стек активити для этого и есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView позволяет отображать содержимое страницы в вашей активити.
`Intent.ACTION_VIEW`открывает браузер, который не зависит от вашего приложения. Может быть вам нужен именн он?

Вот пример

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```